# Modify Swift itself

Tags: function, swift

Is it possible to modify Swift itself?

I use a few functions all the time, and rather than adding those functions to each .swift file by copying and pasting or my user collection in the code snippet library, I'd like to have them be top-level functions.

To try and accomplish this, I created a LanguageModifications.swift file with these functions in them. This worked initially, but it just ended in problems with views being presented and over-complication.

LanguageModifications.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LanguageModifications: UIViewController {
    // Timed delays
    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }

    // Alert
    func alertWithTitleAndMessage(title: String, message: String) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could add these functions to the Swift language itself so I can access them in every file without a thought? Thanks!

Comment: Subclasses, categories, functions vs methods, modules. Never ever copy-paste a function from one place of your code to another place of your code. In any programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your functions like `delay` as functions in a file, not inside any class or struct.  This isn’t Java, functions don’t have to be chaperoned :-)

The Swift standard library is full of functions that don’t live inside classes, like `println`, `map`, `sort` (those latter two being similar to the methods on `Array`, but that work on any kind of collection).

This isn’t really “modifying” Swift. This is just how Swift works – define functions and use them.  There’s no rule that you have to use classes at all.

Comment: Didn't work because the `alertWith...` function can't work without a class. Specifically, because of `self...`

Comment: You don’t have to use self.  Pass the class in as an argument.

Comment: What would I use as the type?

Comment: Using String just gets the error that it doesn't have member named presentViewController, which makes sense.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. I'm getting an error when trying to use it. SomeViewController does not have a member named `alertWithTitleAndMessage`

Comment: You’re declaring `alertWithTitleAndMessage` not inside anything, just at the top level of a file, and you’re not calling it as `self.alertWithTitleAndMessage`, right?  Trust me, this works.  Tinker with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68113/discussion-between-shaan-singh-and-airspeed-velocity).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Swift's [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)?

> Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or
>   enumeration type. This includes the ability to extend types for which
>   you do not have access to the original source code (known as
>   retroactive modeling). Extensions are similar to categories in
>   Objective-C. (Unlike Objective-C categories, Swift extensions do not
>   have names.)

Comment: While extensions are cool, don’t think that for a function to exist, it has to be written as an extension of a class or struct.  Your `delay` function is really a free function, not something you should extend a class with.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity So what would you say a good use of extensions is? Only extending functions already within a class or struct?

Comment: If a function really feels like it “belongs” with a specific class or struct, use an extension.  If the first, most important, argument to a function is a particular class/struct, that’s a sign it might be a good extension.  If all the arguments are kind of equal, then it’s a free function.  Also, there are certain things that cannot be done with extensions currently, like constrained generic functions, that have to be free functions (hopefully some kind of traits-like ability to write extensions on protocols will come at some point in the future)

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity That makes a lot of sense. By that logic, my two functions delay and alertWith are free functions.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use Swift's [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) feature.

As Apple's developer site describes it, extensions allow you to extend existing types with protocols. For example, extending the `Double` datatype to include unit conversions funcs.

You should be able to define your `alertWithTitleAndMessage` func in an extension of UIViewController:

```
extension UIViewController: LanguageModifications {
    // Alert
    func alertWithTitleAndMessage(title: String, message: String) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The above will then extend the `UIViewController` and add a definition of `alertWithTitleAndMessage`.

For `delay`, you don't really need to define it in the extension. It can be a loose func in another *.swift file as pointed out by Airspeed Velocity. It has no reliance on the `UIViewController` instance, so there's no reason to add it to every one.

Comment: "The above will then extend the `UIViewController` with definitions of `LanguageModifications`”  Not quite – you actually have to implement the features there as well.  You can’t implement `LanguageModifications` once and then mix it into multiple classes, as you’re implying.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @AirspeedVelocity! I updated my answer to reflect that, and mentioned your comment regarding delay as well.